# An empty cell on tableView + CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

Can someone tell me why it don't return `cell` for me? I really don't now why. On "`cellTableViewCell`" I have only outlets with label's. 
Or I need to read at func `viewWillAppear`?

```
var nazwaTab:[String] = []
func getContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
    return (appDelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext)!
}
func wczytaj(wartosc:String) -> String {
    var wartosc2 = wartosc
    let request: NSFetchRequest<Ostatnie> = Ostatnie.fetchRequest() 
    do {
        let result = try getContext().fetch(request)
        for liczby in result {
            if let str = liczby.value(forKey: "nazwa") as? String
            {
                wartosc2 = str
                nazwaTab.append(wartosc2)
                nazwaTab.last
            }
            print(nazwaTab)
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
    return wartosc2
}
}
extension tabViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return nazwaTab.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! cellTableViewCell
    cell.dlugoscLabel.text = dlugoscTab[indexPath.row] as! String
    cell.nazwaLabel.text = nazwaTab[indexPath.row]
    cell.szerokoscLabel.text = szerokoscTab[indexPath.row] as! String
    return cell
}
}
```

Comment: when is wczytaj being called?

Comment: if you set a breakpoint in cellForRowAt are the values in the array what you expect?  are the label outlets what you expect?

Comment: @JonRose it's empty, How can I take value from request to table? all view here -> [link](http://www.wklej.org/id/3043967/)

Comment: Where do you call `reloadData()` on the table view? And be aware that `wartosc2` returns only `one` string (the last value for key `nazwa` in the array)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set UITableViewDelegate like this :
 `class tabViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {`

and in viewDidLoad:

```
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self
```